# Calculations and display in label

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm having a small bit of trouble trying to get this piece of code working. I received some answers related to this code bit but it was solving a different issue.

Basically two things for testing purposes that I would like to see working correctly here. One when I try to display dist I would like it to actually get the number that is inputted in the Text Field. Currently when I input something it comes up as zero. (I set it up for doubles cause often a double may be used). The other thing is when I place the timePassed into the display instead of dist it comes up with a serious of numbers that should be the amount of time passed between these two buttons. I'm not sure why but it often displays a negative number and the numbers are a little on the high side to begin with. Any ideas or help is always appreciated. (I'm trying to get these to display on the screen correctly because once I know they are working correctly then I can put them into a calculation and have the calculation display).

```
-(IBAction)triggerDown:(id)sender{
    [timeStart release];
    timeStart = [[NSDate alloc] init];


}

-(IBAction)triggerUp:(id)sender{
    double calc, dist;
    int mph;
    NSString *display;
    NSTimeInterval timePassed = [timeStart timeIntervalSinceNow]*1000;
    if ([distance.text length]== 0) {
        display = @"Please enter a distance";
    }
    else{
        dist = [distance.text doubleValue];
        display = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d MPH",dist];


    }
    speed.text = display;


    [display release];
}
```

Just so you understand what is happening. When triggerDown is pressed it is a button that passes the starting time. Then when that same button is released the triggerUp button is called and it is supposed to get the time that passed between the two as well as do calculations. (Calculations haven't been written in yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the negative (and too large by modulus) time: your timeStart is in the past, so when you do [timeStart timeIntervalSinceNow] you get a negative interval. Since timeStart will *always* be in the past, you can just multiply the interval by -1 to get the positive number.
Furthermore, when you multiply the interval a thousand, you turn a second into a thousand seconds - you need to divide instead to get seconds from milliseconds.

As for displaying the 0 in display - try setting the text field's value to the label directly: speed.text = distance.text. Will it work? If not, make sure the text field is connected to the outlet ("distance").

Comment: Thank you. The actual time I am trying to get for my calculation would be a millisecond time. So should I be doing /-1000 or *-1000 or just *-1? As for the other one I will give that a shot. Thank you :)

Comment: Oh as for the other one. It's not to important if I can get it to display. I'm mainly concerned that I will be able to use the textfields input have it converted into a number so that I can use it for calculations. Does it appear that it will take the input from distance and convert it into a double in dist?

Comment: Oh, if you want to display time in milliseconds, then *-1000 is correct, sorry I didn't understand that. Calling doubleValue on the text should get you the numeric value, yes - but note that it will be quite vulnerable to user errors in input, so you may want to consider using, say, picker control to select the values.

Comment: Oh ya true. You mean like the spinner in Android? I wouldn't even know how to pull that off in xcode lol. I'll have to maybe come up with a good way to check and see if it is a value that can be used. Btw in C, if they input an int number instead of a double will it still be able to handle it or is this a problem in c? Also thanks for all the help.

Comment: You sure there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with dist or distance from what you can tell. I must have something wrong because I plugged in `display = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d MPH",distance.text];` to see what it displays on the screen. I input 50 and I got like 8050302 displaying on the screen. Any clue what might be going on?

Comment: You're printing an NSString* as integer (so you're effectively printing out the memory address). Use %@ instead of %d. As for the other question - yes, if they input an integer it'll be parsed as a double, but you probably still need to at least trim it, or, better yet, throw away all non-numeric characters.